# What's the difference between Lord and God?

Tags: word-meaning

Are **God** and **Lord**  one and the same thing? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Also, *Lord* can be an honorific to a human, God cannot! :)

Comment: You can take a look here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64284/are-lord-and-god-interchangeable [suggested by @Peace]

Comment: I like this one. **God bless you** sounds alright, whereas **Lord bless you** sounds like a **lord** in feudal era.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly interchangeable in all contexts.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[Lord](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lord)**

> **(in the Christian religion)** God or Jesus Christ

[**God**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/god)

> (UK) **(in some religions)** the being who made the universe and is believed to have an effect on all things
>
> (US) **(esp. in Christian, Jewish, and Muslim belief)** the being that created and rules the universe, the earth, and its people

So, **Lord** usually refers to God or Christ in an specific religion, it's used by christians to name their god or his son.

As pointed by Maulik V. **[Lord](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lord)** is also

> A man of noble rank or high office; a nobleman.

In this case you can not apply the word **God**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about English translations of the Bible, you might want to ask this on a board about Judaism or Hebrew, as I think the answer is that those two English terms are translations of two different names used in the Bible